# write text to a text file in sharepoint library using csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a text file in sharepoint library. I want to append some text to it.
I have below code  which is able to read the text inside this text file but I am facing some problem in writing to this file.

```
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File f in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
                if (f.Name == "test1.txt")
                {
                    FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, (string)f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInformation.Stream))
                    {
                        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter wr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileInformation.Stream))
                    {
                        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                        wr.Write("HI");
                       // Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                }
            }
```

I am getting the exception that `Stream is not writable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListItem item = sharedList.GetItemById(writeID);
oContext.Load(item);
oContext.ExecuteQuery();

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = item.File;
oContext.Load(file);
oContext.ExecuteQuery();

byte[] writeBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(htmlString);

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(writeBytes);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(oContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl, stream, true);

oContext.Load(file);
oContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

where "oContext" --> SharePoint client context, "writeID" --> File ID and "htmlString" --> the content to write